# How should I handle a change of address for a Student Pilot License in the USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, student-pilot

I have moved to another place from current address with in same city, Do I have to change my address to the new one on my FAA Student Pilot License? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your address with the FAA online.  You do not need to get a new plastic certificate.

http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/airmen_services/

Comment: Thanks, i found out that for the student pilots also has to update their student pilot document